# Knockout.js Using "with" Binding woes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have an application that has the following setup (more or less):

**JS**

```
var ObjectVM = function(data) {
    var me = this;
    me.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    //Set other properties
    ...

    me.isSelected(false);
};
var VM = function () {
    var me = this;
    me.Records = [];
    me.Selected = ko.observable(undefined);
    me.Select = function (rec) {
        if (rec.hasChanges == undefined) {
            //attach editable functionality
            ko.editable(record);
        }
        rec.isSelected(true);
        rec.beginEdit();
        if (me.Selected() != undefined) {
            if (me.Selected().hasChanges()) {
                me.Selected().rollback();
            }
            me.Selected().isSelected(false);
            me.Selected().commit();
        }
        me.Selected(rec);
        //Do some hiding/showing of form...
    };
    me.Init = function(){
       $.ajax({...,
          success: function(data){
          for(var i = 0;i< data.length;i++){
           me.Records.push(new ObjectVM(data[i]));
          }
       }
    };
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
     RECORDS DISPLAY GRID (Pretend it's a table with 5 columns and 10 rows)
</div>
<div data-bind="with: Selected">
   <form id="editRec">
     <label>Name</label>
      <input data-bind="value: name" />
   </form>
</div>
```

I have a click binding setup on the table rows that calls VMs Select funciton. Using the "with" binding removes the form when Selected() is undefined  and adds back when Selected() has a record.  The issue that every time this occurs, I am losing my validation, tabs, and event bindings (non-KO bindings) that were attached to the form.  The application functions perfectly, but with some performance hits when changing between records, as it is having to re-add the form, setup validation, ui config, and bindings.

Is there a way to have the form stay on the page, keeping my bindings and setup, or am I going to forced to deal with the hit every time the Selected value is changed?

Comment: What version of KO are you using? I think I read somewhere that in 2.2  this shouldn't happen anymore (not positive about that)

Comment: Currently on 2.1, I will give that a try now and let you know!

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker no dice on the update, and I was so hopeful :(

Comment: @jjperezaguinaga I see what you're saying, but I would rather reward those who have properly answered my question.  When I ask for the best way to slice an apple, and i have 2 responses for changing cat litter...whatcha gonna do?

Comment: Eat the litter! Just kidding, I see your point, hopefully you get better answers in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the `with` binding treats its contents as a template and re-renders any time the `with` value changes. The only way to avoid the re-rendering is to not use `with`.

```
<div>
   <form id="editRec">
     <label>Name</label>
      <input data-bind="value: Selected().name" />
   </form>
</div>
```

Of course, if `Selected` can sometimes be `undefined`, this will not work, and you must look for another solution. The best one is to use a custom binding that sets up your event handlers, validation, tabs, etc.

```
<!--ko with: Selected-->
<div data-bind="setUpStuff: true">
   <form id="editRec">
     <label>Name</label>
      <input data-bind="value: name" />
   </form>
</div>
<!--/ko-->
```

A third alternative to avoid some re-rendering and also support an `undefined` value is to use Knockout 2.2 and the `if` binding (and avoid `with`). In 2.2, the `if` binding will only re-render if the value goes falsy to truthy, but not if it changes from one truthy value to another.

```
<!--ko if: Selected-->
<div data-bind="setUpStuff: true">
   <form id="editRec">
     <label>Name</label>
      <input data-bind="value: Selected().name" />
   </form>
</div>
<!--/ko-->
```

Comment: For some reason, using Selected().name does not populate the input field's value.  the custom binding is essentially what I am doing currently when the record is selected.

Comment: Notice I have `Selected().name` because `Selected` is an observable.

Comment: Yes, that is the way it was in HTML, i just forgot to add the () in the comment

Comment: Acutally, i tried testing this without the form, just straight HTML, and it worked.  I'll see how far down this road I can go.. Thanks!

Comment: I added a section about using `if` to guard against an `undefined` value.

Comment: Would it be against any best practices to place it within the value? ==> value: Selected() ? Selected().name : '' ?

Comment: If you want to do it that way, you're better off with `Selected() && Selected().name`. Best practice would be that the `with` binding doesn't re-render, but we have to deal with that. I've made a fork of Knockout (https://github.com/mbest/knockout) that includes a `with` binding that doesn't re-render when the value changes.