# Knockout's "with" binding loses events on contained bindings

Tags: knockout.js

After looking around I have seen a number of people dealing with problems arising from the way Knockout handles `with` bindings, specifically relating to the removal and replacement of DOM elements inside elements applying the `with` binding. I see one case at [Prevent "with" binding from removing DOM elements (Knockout.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243698/prevent-with-binding-from-removing-dom-elements-knockout-js), and a related question at [Knockout.js Using "with" Binding woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163937/knockout-js-using-with-binding-woes/). I have even followed some of the discussion about this problem area at https://github.com/mbest/knockout/issues/9 and https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/476.

I'm led to understand that there has been improvement in versions starting with 2.2.0, but despite all these improvements, I'm still seeing a problem. I have demonstrated it in a JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/bluemonkmn/dSp3L/ whose code is copied below for quick reference.

```
<div data-bind="with: sampleObj">
    <button id="bob" data-bind="text:sampleValue"></button>
    <button data-bind="click:$root.update" id="update">Update</button>
</div>

var sample = ko.observable({
    sampleValue: "Demo"
});
ko.applyBindings({
    sampleObj: sample,
    update: function () {
        sample({
            sampleValue: sample().sampleValue + "x"
        });
    }
});
bob.onclick = function () {
    alert("bob");
};
```

When you click on the first button, an alert pops up. Then click on the second button, which replaces the view model's value. So far so good. But then notice the event handler for the first button is gone, and clicking on it no longer displays a message.

I've tried creating a really cheap replacement for the "with" binding as follows:

```
  ko.bindingHandlers.safeWith = {
     'init': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        return { 'controlsDescendantBindings': true };
     },
     'update': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var dataValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (dataValue) {
           childContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(dataValue);
           ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(childContext, element);
        }
     }
  };
```

And this works great for retaining the event handlers on the elements within the with block. However, I then discovered that some event handlers get doubled every time this happens because they *aren't* removed. I've demonstrated this in an updated version of the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/bluemonkmn/dSp3L/2/

When you click on the first button you still get the message, and it continues to work even after you click the second button to update the value. But if you click on the second button again, you'll notice that the number of times the event is being handled doubles each time the value is updated now.

Is there a simple way to fix this "with" implementation. I would rather not go with a forked copy of `knockout.js` because I want to be able to keep up with the latest version. Ideally I just want a binding handler like `withlight` that can stand alone without requiring a fork of `knockout.js`, and which will also reflect the value of an updated view model without losing event handlers.

**Clarification:** The click event that's displaying the alert in my real code is actually an event handler that's being attached by code similar (I believe) to that seen in jQuery-UI where you just call an initialization function on a DOM element, and it adjusts the DOM and sets up events to make ti work like a nice control. I don't have control over how this event is attached except to determine when this high-level function is called that sets everything up.

Comment: What is the widget if not jqueryui? Is it kendo? what control? I'm still unclear what you don't have control over, if you can add bindings to the element. You may be able to run a tool function to re-attach the behavior during the click (if kendo, i know it has event handlers).

Comment: @danludwig We have a kind of corporate set of controls that was developed on top of and in parallel to jQuery-UI. I may be able to get these controls updated, but it can't be a hack just to make certain use cases with knockout work. It seemed to me that a better "with" implementation would be a cleaner solution. After all, it's "with" that is essentially removing the events unnecessarily. All I want to do is refer to a specific scope without having to include the parent variable name in every data-bind attribute. I don't want the DOM to be moving around.

Comment: It's not exactly an answer to this question, but is quite relevant in our circumstances -- see http://stackoverflow.com/q/21415232/78162

Answer (score 0):

Is avoiding the `with` binding an option?

```
<div>
    <button id="bob" data-bind="text: sampleObj().sampleValue"></button>
    <button data-bind="click: update" id="update">Update</button>
</div>
```

**Update**

It looks like with, along with other control flow bindings like if, ifnot, and foreach, are supposed to add and remove elements from the dom *when they are bound to an observable*.

So I'm wondering could it be feasible to try making your child context non-observable? For example instead of this,

```
var sample = ko.observable({
    sampleValue: "Demo"
});
```

...try something more like this?

```
var sample = {
    sampleValue: ko.observable('Demo')
};
```

That way, your observable isn't getting destroyed each time, we're only mutating the value. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VFKR6/1/

...and here is what the code looks like:

```
<!-- unchanged from the OP -->
<div data-bind="with: sampleObj">
    <button id="bob" data-bind="text:sampleValue"></button>
    <button data-bind="click:$root.update" id="update">Update</button>
</div>

// don't make sample observable, only make sample.sampleValue observable
var sample = {sampleValue: ko.observable("Demo")};
ko.applyBindings({
    sampleObj: sample,
    update: function () { sample.sampleValue(sample.sampleValue() + 'x'); }
});
bob.onclick = function() {alert("bob");};
```

This is doing what you wanted, changing the text of the button in the child context, and it doesn't destroy the bob.onclick event.

Comment: You didn't say anything about jqueryui in the question. Perhaps you should update it with real code instead of a stripped example.

Comment: The real code uses a control library that's not jQuery-UI, but is based on jQuery-UI conventions and builds on some jQuery-UI controls. I'll update the question with that clarification, but I think it's not practical to include all the real code, and shouldn't be necessary if I can explain the restrictions I'm dealing with.

Comment: Yes, avoiding the with binding is probably an option, but isn't there a way to write something similar to the with binding that would have a similar effect (implicitly include a parent context in each child element's bindings without all the DOM restructuring complications) since it seems like such a simple thing?

Comment: I think I just need to, instead of calling applyBindingsToDescendants, call the update function of every descendant binding. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It doesn't appear so. Even if you could, that's something that could break if you change to using ko minified in production, since the minified version doesn't expose the entire api surface that the unminified version does.

Comment: Come to think of it, don't I just need to change my `init` function to call `applyBindings` on `element` passing in the `valueAccessor()` value wrapped in an observable? Then the update doesn't need to do anything because KO takes care of the rest?

Comment: Can you do that and still maintain the reference to $root and the other ancestral binding context(s)? I thought applyBindings was only for root element context. BTW I updated my answer with another option and a working fiddle.